# Could not find method namespace() for arguments [com.android.mylib] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-library

I am trying to create a library in android studio by following this official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library). But in this particular project, I am facing this issue. if I create new project and create new lib I don't face any issue. It means something is wrong with this project only.

**My Lib Gradle**

> plugins {
> id 'com.android.library'
> }

```
android {
    namespace 'com.android.mylib'
    compileSdkVersion 33

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 33

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

**App Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
    testBuildType "beta"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.etc"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 327
```

> **I have searched some questions, but according to those answers, everything seems correct. i have invalidated cache and restarted the android studio as well**.
>
> Here is the error.

```
 A problem occurred evaluating project ':mylibrary'

Caused by:
```

org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method namespace() for arguments [com.example.mylibrary] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

Comment: did you find out what the problem was?

Comment: It was an error in android studio. I had to create another app and shift the code in there. Especially, when it comes to M1 macs usually apps are not fully optimised.

Answer (score 8):

That is the problem with the Gradle version used in the app some plugins want latest version of the Gradle

Try to change the Gradle version in:

1. **android/gradle/gradle-wrapper-properties** file change the gradle version
   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
2. **android/build.gradle** file
   Under dependencies change the following line to use the latest gradle version
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5.2'

Comment: My project was not compatible with the `7.5.2` version, so I solved it by changing the gradle version to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'`