# How to create a fake domain for a flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to revive an old project from a couple of years back. I have a lot of issues but first, I am trying to get the app to run in debug mode.

When I execute flutter run --debug I get the following error:

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\DealDiligence\deal_diligence\android\app\build.gradle' line: 26
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method namespace() for arguments [com.example.deal_diligence] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.
> Cannot invoke method substring() on null object

Here is what I have in the build.gradle file:

```
android {
    namespace "com.example.deal_diligence"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
```

I no longer have the domain I originally used to create the project so how do I create a fake domain so the app will run?

Thanks

Comment: The "package name" has nothing to do with a "domain" apart from happening to look like one. Search for the actual error messages **Could not find method namespace() for arguments** and **Failed to notify project evaluation listener. compileSdkVersion is not specified** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75493247/could-not-find-method-namespace-for-arguments-com-android-mylib-on-extension https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094037/android-studio-failed-to-notify-project-evaluation-listener-error
Both point to it being an issue with the gradle version